# Mongoose Model.find -> Edit -> Callback?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, middleware

Sorry for the vague title, but what I'm trying to do is the following:
I've got 2 mongoose Models: posts and users (which can be the author of a post)

```
const Post = new Schema({
    title: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    content: {type: String, required: true},
    date_created: {type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now},
    authorId: {type: String, required: true},             // ObjectId
    author: {type: Schema.Types.Mixed},
    page: {type: Boolean, required: true, default: false}
});
```

`post.find()`
*mongoose sends query to MongoDB*
*MongoDB returns documents*
*Middleware that retrieves the author based on the `authorId` property*
*Add found user to the posts `author` field*
`post.find callback`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, [mongoose document references and population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) will do this for you.

```
const Post = new Schema({
    // ...
    author: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: "User"}
});
```

the `ref: "User"` tells Mongoose to use the "User" type as the object type. Be sure you have a "User" model defined with Mongoose or this will fail.

to load the full object graph, use the `populate` method of a query:

```
Post
  .findOne(/* ... */)
  .populate('author')
  .exec(function (err, story) {
    // ...

  });
```

P.S. I cover this and more in [my MongooseJS Fundamentals](https://sub.watchmecode.net/series/mongoosejs-fundamentals/) screencast package.

Comment: Thanks! 
This indeed did the trick! ^^
Code is now working :)
`const body = yield this.Model.find()
                .populate('authorId')
                .lean();`